# TypeScript: access outer "this" from a nested classic function, not breaking the linter "no-this-alias" rule

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

We use [Airbnb's eslint config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) in our TypeScript project, and it includes the [no-this-alias rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-this-alias.md).

And it makes me wonder how I can access the outer `this` from a nested classic function, without breaking this rule?

Here's the code:

```
class MyClass {
 
  name: string;

  target: EventTarget;
 
  constructor(name: string, target: EventTarget) {
    this.name = name;
    this.target = target;
  }
 
  initEventHandlers() {
    const self = this;
    function exampleEventHandler(this: EventTarget, e: Event) {
      console.log(this.somethingFromTheTarget);
      console.log(self.somethingFromMyClass);
    }
    this.target.addEventListener('exampleEvent', exampleEventHandler);
  }
}
```

The event handler function is called from the event library, using `fn.call(this, e)` to set the `this` to the event target, in the event handler's scope. Obviously, using the arrow function is not applicable here.

The linter has a problem with the `const self = this;` line.

I know this is allowed: `const { thisOneProperty } = this`, and then one can use the `thisOneProperty` in the nested function code. But that does no good when the property value is updated.

This also works: `const myClass = { t: this };`, and then I can do `myClass.t` to access it. But that's so ugly.

What is the "clean" way to access the MyClass's `this` from within the event handler function then?

Comment: Is there any reason why this won't work? https://tsplay.dev/kNreaw  Using an arrow function and accessing the target from `this.target` of the class rather than `this` of the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here "The event handler function is called from the event library, using fn.call(this, e)"

Comment: You could capture the code accessing the outer object in an arrow function, and call that arrow function in the handler, but this will likely get ugly if there are more interactions with the outer object.

Comment: @LindaPaiste the code in my post is simplified. In the real code, there are many targets and using the same handler function. I mentioned the `fn.call(this, e)` just to show that the event handler functions are called by setting the `this` to the object that is emitting the event.

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```js
class MyClass {
 
  name: string;

  target: EventTarget;
 
  constructor(name: string, target: EventTarget) {
    this.name = name;
    this.target = target;
  }
 
  initEventHandlers() {
    const self = {
      somethingFromMyClass: this.somethingFromMyClass.bind(this)
    };

    function exampleEventHandler(this: EventTarget, e: Event) {
      console.log(this.somethingFromTheTarget);
      console.log(self.somethingFromMyClass);
    }
    this.target.addEventListener('exampleEvent', exampleEventHandler);
  }
}
```